# GCS: Update storage class on objects that are different from the bucket storage class using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-storage

We have a bucket with REGIONAL storage class. Inside bucket, there are objects with NEARLINE and COLDLINE storage classes. I tried to create GCS lifecycle rule with `SetStorageClass:

```
  lifecycle_rule {
    action {
      type          = "SetStorageClass"
      storage_class = "REGIONAL"
    }
    condition {
      with_state = "ANY"
      age        = 0
    }
  }
```

A week after applying the rule I still see objects in NEARLINE and COLDLINE storage. Also I noticed that on Google Console there is not option to create Lifecycle rule for changing storage class to REGIONAL:
[image]

NOTE: in terraform plan output I see the required changes.

UPDATE: according to SetStoargeClass paragraph: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#setstorageclass it's not allowed to upgrade the storage class.

Answer (score 0):

I think if it's impossible to change it in the console, it's also impossible do this action from `Terraform` code.

The `Terraform` resource indicates changes, but in the apply can't apply the action.

You can maybe think about another solution, you can create a new regional bucket, and migrate the objects from the old bucket to the new.

You need to check the impacts in differents pieces of your code, because if you create a new bucket, you have to change the name in your code too.

Comment: `tf apply` passed successfully and I see a new lifecycle rule but it's looking weird. This rule doesn't have an action name. 
Another option is to change the storage class using `gsutil` but the amount of objects in the bucket will require a lot of time to do it.

Comment: Are you using the last version of `Terraform` `google` provider ?

Comment: not the latest, v1.3